# Monitor where SQS messages goes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I was trying to monitor where and what consumes my messages in my SQS. I am using sqs-consumer to get all the messages available in my queues but the problem is I turned down the service that consumes those messages yet still being consume by a service and I don't know where. Is there a way to check where and what consumes the messages from my sqs queues ? Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps you could modify the Resource Policy on the SQS queue and `Deny` access to anything that isn't the app you trust. Then, wait to see who complains!

Comment: oohh okay, thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/sqs-who-consumed-messages/

Copied directly from the above link:

It isn't possible to directly identify who consumes messages from Amazon SQS. However, client-side logging can provide some insight.

- Review the Amazon SQS resource policy. It's a best practice to implement least-privilege access and to verify that SQS queues aren't publicly accessible. Restrict the SQS queue ReceiveMessage action to specific AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) users or roles. For more information, see Amazon SQS security best practices.
- Review all AWS Lambda function triggers for the SQS queue. If a Lambda function is configured with an active SQS event source, then it's possible that the Lambda function consumed the message.

To confirm who polled an SQS queue, contact AWS Support and provide a list of the following:

- Message IDs
- Request IDs
- Corresponding sent and received timestamps

Comment: Thank you! :D I've been searching a way to monitor where message goes. This helped me a lot!